# what is considered average request processing time?

Tags: diagnostics

What is normal time range for request processing?

Comment: Are we to assume you mean web GET requests?

Comment: Yeah very subjective question - could be an hour for a batch system, could be a second for a busy web server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything between 50ms to 500ms would be good.

This of course is only the server side. Have a look at [Yahoo's Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and [Firebug YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) on learning and measuring the response times on the client side as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my limited experience, the user will generally notice an interactive site as being slow if responses are routinely taking over one second.  A few seconds or more can be maddening.  By "interactive", I mean something where the user is going to be generating a lot of pages, like a forum.

Here's an interesting article / book snippet about response times: http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Anything slower than [8 seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_performance) is generally considered too long. 1-2 seconds is average for most heavy websites.